# 3way switch where one switch ends up using a white on the common, the other switch the white is connected to another white

Tags: electrical

[image]The switch where the two whites are connected n tucked away, the black n red from the same cable are connected to the brass, the remaining black is connected to the Blk common screw, the lower switch, the black n red are connected to the brass screws in the same formation as the other switch, the white is connected to the Blk common. When the lower switch has the light on, both switches can turn the light off n on, but when you turn the light off from the lower switch you can't turn it back on from the other switch, should I jump the Blk common to the connected white in the back of the top switch? At

Comment: Do not start to switch wires.  Three ways are confusing enough.  Post pictures of both switches and wires at the light, with the breaker off.  Labelling where each wire goes to what screw will be helpful to you also.

Comment: Something is really messed up here. White is *usually* neutral, and that is almost certainly the case with the two whites that are together in a red wire nut. Whites *can* be travelers in a 3-way switch, but that does not appear to be the case here. white should never be the common of a 3-way switch, because that should either be incoming hot on one end or switched hot on the other end.

Comment: I found that the power from the upper switch went out as a red wire but at the lower switch became a hot white

Comment: Opening one of the lights I see 2 white wires connected with a red wire

Comment: There are three lights connected on these three way switches so uncertain what they did in the other two lights